# Check if topic name already exists

Tags: ros, python, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

How can I check if a topic name already exists with Python?

I think this can be a noob question, but I have not managed to find it...

Regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/94856/check-if-topic-name-already-exists/) by [BeLi](https://answers.ros.org/users/7711/beli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-10-27

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) on 2016-02-16**:
This question is with good cause, as one could avoid subscribing to topics not being out there. I ran into the same problem in `roscpp` and there seems to be no solution, but subscribing to the topics having in mind and checking for incoming msgs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AFAIK there is not. The reason is that there is nothing such as "creating" a topic. Topics are implicitly considered as "existing" as soon as one node starts publishing on it. To this extent, if you really want to see if a ""topic exists"" you should create a subscriber and wait for a message to come. This is the best approximation you can get.

Also, this is a perfectly valid behavior for two nodes to emit on the same topic (see /tf for instance).

On a more general point of view, you should not do that when designing your node, please use meaningful names for your topic instead (aka in, out, position, velocity, etc.) even if they create name clash.

Making sure that a topic name is the duty of the roslaunch XML file and of the architect (the guy who write this file). It is not your role as a node designer.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2013-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [basheersubei](https://answers.ros.org/users/7676/basheersubei/) on 2013-10-28**:
surely, you mean create a subscriber, not a publisher, right?

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2013-10-28**:
Indeed, fixed! Thanks for reporting.

**Comment by [BeLi](https://answers.ros.org/users/7711/beli/) on 2013-10-29**:
Thaks for your reply and explanation Thomas.

My intention was to check if a topic have been registered in the ROS Master, but from your explanation I gather that this is not possible, at least in the way I was trying to do it.

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2016-08-09**:
What do you mean by create a subscriber and *wait* for a message to come? I tried creating a subscriber but it doesn't know immediately once the topic is present. I find that it takes upwards of 30 seconds to know about the topic (if the subscriber is created before the publisher).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could use rospy.get_published_topics() to get all the names of all the published topics. A simple comparison would then tell you if your particular topic is already being published.

---

Originally posted by [DC](https://answers.ros.org/users/29915/dc/) with karma: 81 on 2017-04-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8